# How can I test whether the URL bar will not be displayed in my app without deploying to the Play Store?

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

I made a release apk of my app. Installed it via the adb tool on my smartphone. I am using CustomTab to launch an url. Now I am testing it on my phone, but I still see the urlbar.

I did everything what google expected of me (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/integration-guide/).

- Created an intent-filter

```
     <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="secure.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

- On the server I added: https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

```
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://secure.example.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.example.android",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "example_fingerprint"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am getting the impression that I only can test it if the urlbar is removed while running the app if it is deployed to the playstore and if I install it from the playstore.